# What does Overlay files (*.ovl files) contain about GIS data and how to read them?

Tags: import

Recently, I started dealing with Overlay files (*.ovl files) and my focus is to read the data from OVL files and display them.

Could you guide me as to what these files are and provide a way to read the content both via product and via programming?

Answer (score 2):

The Geogrid viewer and the Software that is designed for using .ovl can read both binary (new OVL) and ASCII (old OVL) format, but GPSBABEL only can read the ASCII one.

The format is copyrighted by EADS, so you will have little chance to get it read without using their software.

I heard that TTQV can read the binary format too, but I guess they have paid to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

I just searched for this using Google and it looks like `*.ovl` files may be [Geogrid-viewer ascii overlay files](http://www.gpsbabel.org/htmldoc-1.4.2/fmt_ggv_ovl.html) that can be read by GPSBabel.